# Folder (Created during installation ) in Wix Installer not visible for all Users

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, directory, wix3.5

I have developed a setup using wix and it works perfect for admin login.But i want my application working for all the users including the admin.So i have set **InstallScope="perMachine"** in package element. But for maintaning some **logs,Help documents etc** am creating a folder in **%appdata% \ ApplicatinName** and will save a log file when my application runs but the folder will be created initially during the setup being installed and its working perfect in Administrator login but if i login into  user account , in user account the folder was not created in **%appdata%** path.

My folder(XXX) in appdata was only visible for admin and not visible for other users.How to make same folder visible for all the users including administrator during installation.

In folder,there are templates in my application for eg some templates will be added along with installer which is called as Predefined templates .These predefined templates should be visible for all the users. Along with this users too can create templates which will be saved under the same folder but the user should be only able to see the predefined templates and the template which that user created himself. (ie) He should not be able to see the templates which are created by other user
Regards
Arshad

Comment: If you would like to write to a common folder for all users, try to write to C:\ programName instead of to appdata. This can be a permissions issue.

Comment: @user3165438  my requirement is there are templates in my application for eg some templates will be added along with installer which is called as Predefined templates .These predefined templates should be visible for all the users. Along with this users too can create templates which will be saved under the same folder but the user should be only able to see the predefined templates and the template which that user created himself. (ie) He should not be able to see the templates which are created by other user

Comment: Thanks for the details. I understand that you would like to store templates per user. when you install, the folder is created only for the user the program was installed from his account. Take a look here : http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-add-a-folder-file-to-all-users-application-data

Comment: @user3165438 but atleast initially the predefined templates should be visible for all users from appdata folder na how to do that :( :)(

Comment: That's way I would like you to use `CommonAppDataFolder` instead of `[AppDataFolder]`: [AppDataFolder] = property to the full path of the Roaming folder for the current user.

[CommonAppDataFolder] = the full path to the file directory containing application data for all users

Comment: @user3165438 if i save the templates in [CommonAppDataFolder] then it will be visible for all the users.This scenario is okie for Predefined templates,but user defined templates should be visible only for the users..!

Comment: Did you try that? worth testing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79382/discussion-between-dahsra-and-user3165438).

Comment: @user3165438 here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589632/files-in-appdatafolder-not-visible-for-all-the-users-wix

Answer (score 1):

I ran a test and found this WIX fragment successfully created a folder in the user profile of the installing user, which had security settings that allowed other users to access the folder and its contents:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="MyDataRoot" Name="XXX">
      <Component Id="MyDataRoot" Guid="--MY GUID--">
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\Product\SpecialFolder" Name="Installed" Type="string" Value="yes" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="MyDataRoot" Directory="MyDataRoot" On="uninstall"/>
        <CreateFolder Directory="MyDataRoot">
          <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="Users"/>
        </CreateFolder>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Notes:

1. The above fragment creates a user profile folder for the installing user which can be accessed by other users.  See comment below regarding the security implications of this approach.
2. The actual GUID has been replaced with "--MY GUID--".
3. The `<RegistryValue...>` is required to solve error ICE38: Component MyDataRoot installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
4. The `<RemoveFolder...>` is required to solve error ICE64: The directory MyDataRoot is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
5. I used WIX V3.9 to build the installer package.
6. The installer package was tested by installing on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

However creating a directory in one user profile that is accessed by other users is questionable from a security perspective.  Have you considered changing your application to create a user profile folder when the application starts rather than using the installer to create the user profile folder?

For example your application could use `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to get the current user's application data folder, and create a sub-folder within this folder to store your application's logs.  This approach ensures logs from your application go to the current user's application folder rather than another user's application folder.

Comment: @bradfordg Thanks for the reply.!I would check out this and let you know ..!!

Comment: i tried the same and folder is created only for administrator .For others users folder was not created.NOTE: I haven't add that registry line(i think its not that necessary )

Comment: Creating a user profile folder in an installer, will only create a folder for the installing user (in this case Administrator).  The installation will not create folders for any other user.  If you want your application logs to go to user specific folders, your application should create the required folder not the installer.

Comment: Thanks really..!! But i want my installer to create a folder in appdata where its should be visible to all the users including administrator.How to do this in wix..?

Comment: Updated my answer with more detail (including an explanation of the reasoning behind the registry line).  Could you provide more information in your question: a) What version of WIX are you using? b) What is the target operating system? c) What is the resulting security on the folder created?

Comment: a).Wix3.8 b).64bit windows and for c)Folder is only created for admin while am installing from admin.So i think folder was created as admin and the created folder was not visible in other users

Comment: am using System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) for getting the path. and from your firstPoint you have said that folder can be accessed by other users but i cannot even able to see the folder in other logins

Comment: System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) will return different folders for different users.  When user John runs your application this might return c:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming, but when user Mark runs your application this might return C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79127/discussion-between-dahsra-and-bradfordrg).

Comment: You should try logging on as another user to see what happens when you use a shortcut to the app! Windows Installer will install missing components for the new user on activation of a shortcut (and for a file it will require access to the MSI). That's basically the reason for ICE 38 and multiple users. Windows Installer will install missing data for other users if you set it up correctly.

Comment: @PhilDW how to setUp it corectly